# Смартфон перестал отображаться в андроид студио

Tags: android, android-studio

Пересмотрел ряд подобных тем, но там, как правило, речь шла о том, что устройство не определяется изначально. У меня Lenovo S898t+. Более года использовал для тестирования и проблем не возникало. Кабель проверил, причина не в нем. Подключал к трем разным компам результат отрицательный. Какие могут быть причины?

Comment: Уточняю. Драйвера на компьютере стоят? adb точно включен? Попробуйте к разным портам подключить. Каким образом кабель проверяли?

Comment: Да, драйвера установлены. В один прекрасный момент телефон, просто, перестал отображаться. Я попробовал подключить через другой, "родной" кабель - не помогло (через этот кабель в этот же порт подключаю смартфон жены - его видит). Попытался подключить свой смартфон к еще двум ПК (к ним ранее подключал это же устройство и оно работало), но студия не видит его. Хотя зарядка идет и можно подключать USB накопитель.

Comment: Он должен быть подключен в режиме `MTP`

Comment: @woesss https://androidp1.ru/kak-podklyuchit-android-c-mtp-v-rezhime-usb-nakopitelya-kak-fleshku/ "С версии Android 4.4 KitKat был удален режим USB накопителя и смартфон или планшет можно использовать только как MTP"

Comment: @cosmic_M Попробуйте переустановить adb драйвера, перезагрузить компьютер и очистить кеш студии (file -> invalidate and restart)

Comment: не понял, что конкретно сработало, из последнего, но помогло. iamtihonov оформи как ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте переустановить `adb` драйвера, перезагрузить компьютер и очистить кеш студии